# ¿Porque no encuentra mi variable de code behind en c#?

Tags: c#, aspx

Quiero obtener una variable de mi code behind en c# pero me sale el siguiente error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'qrp' does not exist in the current context
```

Pero si declare correctamente mi variable:

```
 public string qrp { get; set; }
```

La intento imprimir en un alert de la siguiente forma:

```
  alert("<%= qrp.ToString() %>");
```

pero me sale el error de la parte superior, la variable la declaro hasta arriba abajo de donde inicia la clase y la relleno al pasar por un método.

Comment: Si no me equivoco su alerta debería ser asi: `alert("<%=" + qrp.ToString() + "%>");`

Comment: @J.Rodriguez no funciono de la forma en que indico

Comment: Puede colocar el código desde donde invoca el `alert()`?

Comment: déjame adivinar mi estimado, ¿Tienes una variable dentro de un método en CodeBehind la que quiere mostrar, por ejemplo, en un PageLoad ?

Answer (score -1):

utiliza `ViewBag`, ejemplo:

```
ViewBag.qrp = "valor";
```

y el la parte del front lo llamas de esta manera

```
alert('@ViewBag.qrp');
```

Comment: `ViewBag` corresponde a tecnología MVC, el OP lo intenta realizar en WebForms